# Is it possible to do this query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a table called students, containing a list of all the students. Each student can have many courses stored in another table, identified by a student id.

I want to do a query which will get the row from the students table with the info of the student, and also get all of his courses, in one query. The output I want is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [firstName] => Bob
            [lastName] => Smith
            [email] => ....
            [courses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 30
                            [name] => Test Course
                            [price] => 400
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 30
                            [name] => Test Course 2
                            [price] => 300
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

To get the info of students, I would do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE something ='something'
```

To get the courses for a student, I would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE studentId = '5'
```

Is it possible to do both queries at once and get an output like the array above, or do I have to loop through each student and get its courses, then attach it to the array manuallly?

Comment: I think `group_concat` might help. Link: http://www.dougboude.com/blog/1/2009/12/A-SWEET-Little-MySQL-Function-GroupConcat.cfm

Comment: Are you looking for SQL syntax or for the coding to get into your array format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5378180/170365

Comment: I think this is more a PHP question than an SQL question. mySQL will always return a table, not a nested structure like you want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "select * from students inner join courses on studentID = '5' where something  = 'something'"; 
$result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link); 
$id = $row[0]; # corresponding to row in students database
$firstName= $row[1]; # corresponding to row in students database
$lastName = $row[2]; # corresponding to row in students database
$email = $row[3]; # corresponding to row in students database
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo 'id: '.$row[id];
  echo '<br>';
  echo 'name: '.$row[name];
  echo '<br>';
  echo 'price: '.$row[price];
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do `inner join courses on studentId = students.id` rather than hard coding student id as 5? I want to get all the students, not just one at a time.

Comment: @Click Yes just replace '5' with '".$studentId."'

Comment: No, then I'll still be getting it for one student at a time, if I have 100 students I'll have to run this query 100 times for all of them

Comment: @clickupvote You can do it for all students, but it cannot be done in one query. It will take two queries. Basically just add another while loop around the above using select * from students.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by joining the tables together:

```
select s.*, c.*
from students s join
     courses c
     on s.studentid = c.studentid
where s.something = 'something'
```

If you want the student information on one row and the course on another, then it is not possible.  All rows have to have the same columns.

Comment: I want the courses info to be an array on the student row, that's not possible then?

Comment: This doesn't create an multi-d array.

Comment: @Strawberry Its not possible to do a multi d array then except by looping?

Comment: @ClickUpvote I am not sure. I'm waiting for an answer as well. I know it can be done if you process it using PHP for sure though. My guess is no, but I have hope. CakePHP does this, maybe you can dig through their code :D

Answer (score 2):

Basically new code would be:

```
$query = "select * from students"; 
$result = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $id = $row[0]; # corresponding to row in students database
   $firstName= $row[1]; # corresponding to row in students database
   $lastName = $row[2]; # corresponding to row in students database
   $email = $row[3]; # corresponding to row in students database
   echo 'id: '.$id;
   echo '<br>';
   echo 'firstName: '.$firstName;
   echo ' ';
   echo 'lastName: '.$lastName;
   echo '<br>';
   echo 'email: '.$email;
   echo '<br>';
   $query = "select * from courses where id  = '".$id."'"; 
   $result2 = mysql_db_query ($dbname, $query, $link); 
   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
     echo 'name: '.$row2[1]; # corresponding to row in courses database
     echo '<br>';
     echo 'price: '.$row2[2]; # corresponding to row in courses database
     echo '<br>';
   }
}
```